# How to create multiple frames or windows in GUI?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, intellij-idea

I am new to creating GUI. I want to know how to create multiple windows. I want to show another frame if a button is to be clicked. I have searched how and i saw that some people are making another GUI form and just calling the other form i a button was clicked, but i dont understand how.  [image]

Comment: `new JFrame()`.

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) Read that answer for a few free-floating alternatives, and many alternatives that are not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are numerous ways to do this. One of the main ways is to create a new Java Class with its own properties. Here is a nexample:

```
JButton button = new JButton("Button_Leads_To_This_Window");
button.addActionListener( new ActionActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
       NewFrame();
    }
});
```

This will allow the button to call a new window, similar as the way you called the "My Empire" window. For example NewFrame() class will look like this:

```
public static void newFrame()
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                try 
                {
                   UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
                }
                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
                panel.setOpaque(true);
                JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(15, 50);
                textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
                textArea.setEditable(false);
                textArea.setFont(Font.getFont(Font.SANS_SERIF));
                JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(textArea);
                scroller.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
                scroller.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
                JPanel inputpanel = new JPanel();
                inputpanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
                JTextField input = new JTextField(20);
                JButton button = new JButton("Enter");
                DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret) textArea.getCaret();
                caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);
                panel.add(scroller);
                inputpanel.add(input);
                inputpanel.add(button);
                panel.add(inputpanel);
                frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, panel);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                frame.setVisible(true);
                frame.setResizable(false);
                input.requestFocus();
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is more information to the matter:

https://www.thoughtco.com/create-a-simple-window-using-jframe-2034069

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RMz9LYY2g4A

Good luck.